# TSLint mistakes in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I have several mistakes in my code. I'm use Angular 2 + TSLint:

```
constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
--> let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
    this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
}
```

In currentUser i have this error: `message: 'expected variable-declaration: 'currentUser' to have a typedef`;

```
public loginC (username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.post( authURL + loginURL,
                     --> JSON.stringify({ password: password, username: username }))
    .map((response: Response) => {
        let token: string = response.json() && response.json().token;
        if (token) {
          this.token = token;
      --> localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify({token: token, username: username}));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And in `password: password, username: username` this: `message: 'Expected property shorthand in object literal.`
I really understand this. And finalli i can write a simple `model: any {}`;

```
export class LoginComponent {
--> public model: any = {};
public loading: boolean = false;
public error: string = "";
constructor (private router: Router, private authenticationService: ServerDataComponent) {
    // 
}

public login(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.loginC(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(result => {
           --> if (result === true) {
                this.router.navigate(["/table_per"]);
            } else {
                this.error = "Введен неверный логин и/или пароль";
                this.loading = false;
            }
        });
}
```

For any - `Type declaration of 'any' is forbidden`;

Ror result - `expected arrow-parameter: 'result' to have a typedef`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `expected variable-declaration: 'currentUser' to have a typedef` you can define an `interface` for your custom type.

```
export interface User {
  token: string;
}
```

And use it to set the type.

```
let currentUser: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
```

For `Expected property shorthand in object literal` you can use the shorthand syntax when the key name matches the name of the variable.

```
JSON.stringify({token, username})
```

For `Type declaration of 'any' is forbidden` you can try to change the type to `Object`. If not you'll need to declare another `interface` for your model.

```
public model: Object = {};
```

For `expected arrow-parameter: 'result' to have a typedef` you need to set the type of the parameter.

```
.subscribe((result: boolean) => {
```

Comment: i add a `Object`, and now, `Property token does not exist of type Object`

Comment: add this in constructor?

Comment: No, outside of your `class`, you can either create a new file `user.interface.ts` and import it or have it on the same file.

Comment: thanks, it works, and i have two more mistakes, i upadate the code now